# Setup and record outbound traffic from a botnet in a sandbox/secure environment

Tags: windows, logging, botnet, sandbox

How do I record the outbound 'attack' traffic from a botnet on a Windows XP machine? The captured traffic will be in the Windows XP firewall log.

I need to setup some kind of an experiment where I can use a Win XP firewall log for later analysis, for research purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the XP firewall log, just enable it - it works tolerably well.

Better may be to use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which will log the actual data sent out from the machine

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think a real life experiment could work. Setting up a vulnerable XP machine for a fixed amount of time, with logging enabled etc. Though there must be other ways

Comment: @nocker - depending on what you want to do, look on the honeynet.org web pages. They have stacks of data on botnet comms etc

Answer (score 3):

This posting on [Getting Started with Basic Malware Analysis](http://www.zonbi.org/archives/495) was almost built to answer to this question.

The author of the blog post explains using [Remnux](http://zeltser.com/remnux/) with fake DNS, fake services, etc as the gateway to a malware infected Windows XP machine. He also mentions putting a Dionaea instance on the network as well, to see if the infected host attacks it.